# How to process image files using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

There are 100 image files with different colors .I want to get unique image based on the color

Comment: get MD5SUM of the image and remove duplciates

Comment: refer to this article: http://www.hadoopsphere.com/2013/02/data-de-duplication-tactics-with-hdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in **Hadoop/Pig API** for processing Image data.

To process image data using **Pig/MapReduce**, use the following steps:

1. Convert all the images into **Sequence File/Files**

   ```
   Key             Value
   Image_file_id   Image Content
   ```
2. Load this file into **HDFS**.
3. Use any third party library for detection like **"Haar Cascades"** as **UDF in Pig** or call **the Java library in MapReduce** program.